# while algorithm loop in php

Tags: php, algorithm, loops, while-loop

I am trying loop over a set of numbers if I inputted them into the terminal. By calling

```
php scripts/max.php 1 5 9
```

I want a loop that loops over 1, 5, 9 and tells me what the largest number is. I have been throughingly confused with loops but I got this far.

```
$args = $argv; 
array_shift($args); 

if (empty($args)) {
    echo "Expecting numbers as arguments." . PHP_EOL;
    exit(1);
}

$largest = [];

while ( $args++) {
    echo $args . PHP_EOL;
    while($args > $largest) {
        break 2;
    }
}
```

The idea is the loop would take any amount of numbers when inputting them in the terminal and tell me which number is the largest.

Comment: `$args` is array, so `$args++` and `$args > $largest` makes no sense

Comment: I can't use max()cause its an algorithm and I have to do it the long way! Would've used max if I could!

Comment: What have you tried to resolve your problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Ive used while loops, do while, for, and foreach and can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense! I was over thinking it massively!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Throw away all your loops and just do `max($args)`[1](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.max.php)

---

Your code consists of way too much errors:

1. `$args` is array, so `$args++` and `$args > $largest` makes no sense and it's acting on hidden type cast of array
2. `$largest = [];` should be integer, not array.
3. You never assign anything to be `$largest`

---

If that's school assignment, then do it proper way:

```php
$args = $argv; 
array_shift($args); 

if (empty($args)) {
    echo "Expecting numbers as arguments." . PHP_EOL;
    exit(1);
}

$largest = PHP_INT_MIN; // first set it to be smallest possible integer. And since $args is not empty, we will overwrite it

foreach ($args as $arg) {
    // Compare if current element is larger than our current $largest
    if ($arg > $largest) {
        $largest = $arg;
    }
}

echo "Largest number: {$largest}";
```

Comment: You could also set the initial ```$largest``` to the first number ```$largest = array_shift($args)```.